# ¿Como extraer objetos de una imagen de forma automática con Python OpenCv?

Tags: python, imagen, opencv, machine-learning

Estoy realizando un script para detectar y extraer objetos de forma automática para un post procesamiento. Adjunto la imagen inicial, cabe mencionar que solo pretendo detectar imágenes en blanco y negro guardado en un numpy (0 y 255).

[image: Imagen original]

En el proceso de filtrado y para detectar bordes, estructuro lo siguiente:

```
img=np.load("data.npy")
img=transpose(img.T)
img=np.where(img>0,0,1) 

img=img*255

dilate=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,2))
erode = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2,2))

img_=cv2.dilate(img_,dilate,iterations=1)
img_= cv2.erode(img_,erode,iterations=1)

cnts = cv2.findContours(img_, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

image_number = 0

for c in cnts:
    print(image_number)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(img_, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
    ROI = img_[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite("ROI_{}.png".format(image_number), ROI)
    image_number += 1
```

El problema resulta que no detecta correctamente, obteniendo imágenes de un pixel a dos. Incluyo ejemplo a continuación.

[Resultado 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i3Rv.png)
[[Resultado 2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UFAJ.png)

Como objetivo, deseo obtener algo similar:

[image: Objetivo]

PD: Incluyo la data original en un .npy. Ademas de la funcion transpose, ambos en un git (https://github.com/Armando123x/consult)

Comment: no te ayudaria hacer un dilute y erode mas dramatico? Solo estas usando 1 iteracion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al hacer primero dilate y luego erode haces el punto más grueso y luego lo vuelves a la normalidad. Pero si haces primero erode eliminas un poco de ruido y recién haces el dilate para obtener el tamaño original.